# I am not getting matching string

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

This is my data which contains number and string.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1,008$','4,000$','6,000$','10,00$','8,00$','45€','45€']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns = ['A'])
vv=df2[df2['A'].str.match('$')]
```

I want an output like this.

```
0  1,008$
1  4,000$
2  6,000$
3  10,00$
4   8,00$
```

but I am getting this output:

```
Out[144]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A]
Index: []
```

can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A somewhat verbose way using Numpy's `defchararray` module.
I always want to give this some attention.

```
# Using @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's suggestion
# Same function as below but shorter namespace path

df2[np.char.find(df2.A.values.astype(str), '$') >= 0]
```

---

*Old Answer*

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import find

df2[find(df2.A.values.astype(str), '$') >= 0]

        A
0  1,008$
1  4,000$
2  6,000$
3  10,00$
4   8,00$
```

Comment: I've used this a couple of times before (looking at your posts), and `np.char.find` also works, I think.

Answer (score 2):

`str.match` starts matching from the beginning. however, your `$` pattern will be found only at the end.

The fix requires either, a modification to your pattern, or changing the function.

**Option 1**
`str.match` with a modified pattern (so `\$` is matched at the end)  -

```
df2[df2.A.str.match('.*\$$')]

        A
0  1,008$
1  4,000$
2  6,000$
3  10,00$
4   8,00$
```

If you want to be specific about what is matched, you can match only on digits and commas -

```
df2[df2.A.str.match('[\d,]+\$$')]

        A
0  1,008$
1  4,000$
2  6,000$
3  10,00$
4   8,00$
```

Note that this does not account for invalid entries in your column (they're matched as long as they have those characters somewhere in the string, and are terminated by `$`).

---

**Option 2**
`str.contains`

```
df2[df2.A.str.contains('\$$')]

        A
0  1,008$
1  4,000$
2  6,000$
3  10,00$
4   8,00$
```